# How to validate phone number with country code for unit testing scenario

Tags: unit-testing

How to validate phone number with country code with different format. I am using valid phonenumber lengh mehod , and in this using regular expression for phone number to validate like

```
public bool IsValidPhoneNumberLength(string phoneNumber)
    {
        bool isValidPhone = false;
        string pattern = @"^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool result = isValidPhone = regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber);
        return result;
    }
```

And My unit test case mentioned below

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("2345678900"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("0019885021320"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("(212)897-0067"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("1(212)897-0067"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("001(212)897-0067"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("001.212.897.0067"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("001(212)897.00671234"));
        Assert.AreEqual(true, company1.IsValidPhoneNumberLength("001 212 897 0067"));
```

unit test is fails, some of the conditions mentioned in test method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are two problems with this code:

1. You're using regexp to validate a complex input string. regexp is powerful but it has it's limits. So you may fare better by using regexp to *parse* the input into fields and then validate the fields (content, length, etc).

   Also, sometimes it's better to ignore any character that you don't understand rather than trying to say "it's ok if it's here and here but not there." So the task would be much more simple (and more pleasant for the customer) if you just removed anything that isn't a digit from the input and then just checked the length.

   The stripping would fold thousands of cases into one.
2. You do more than one assert in the unit test. This is very bad. If several assertions fail, you will only see the first one. The other ones could give you valuable information about what might be wrong with the last change.